# Elixir Regex Mismatching parenthesis

Tags: regex, elixir

I am trying to run some Regex that matches a vowel and consonant (VC). Ex: "trouble" -> matches "ub". I have some regex:

```elixir
@vowel_regex "([aeiou]|(?<=.)(?<![aeiou])y)"
@consonant_regex "[^#{@vowel_regex}]"

Regex.run(~r/#{@vowel_regex}#{@consonant_regex}/, word)
```

which returns a compile error

```elixir
** (Regex.CompileError) unmatched parentheses at position 59
```

I have tried using `Regex.escape`, but this doesn't match anything

```elixir
"#{@vowel_regex}#{@consonant_regex}"
|> Regex.escape
|> Regex.compile!
|> Regex.run("trouble")

iex(35)> nil
```

I have tried this regex using rubular and it works as expected. https://rubular.com/r/lNuqIROWTXJjhp

Does anyone know what I could be missing?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fP1aEw/1 also raises error, i guess problem is in using `[]` inside `()` inside `[]`, maybe there is another way

Answer (score 1):

```elixir
Regex.run(~r/#{@consonant_regex}/, "trouble")
```

Also fails for me. If you expand it out it it looks like:

```elixir
Regex.run(~r/[^([aeiou]|(?<=.)(?<![aeiou])y)]/, "trouble")
```

I think you error is caused by some `()` parenthesis characters inside `[]` literally being matched, rather than being used to group.

However, this works for me, maybe you can start simpler and expand it to what you need:

```elixir
iex(1)> Regex.run(~r/[aeiou][^aeiou]/, "trouble")
["ub"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that you asked a Regex question, but since you are using Elixir, you can also do this nicely with function clauses and pattern matching. :-)

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  @vowels 'aeiou'

  def vowelconst([]), do: nil

  def vowelconst([vowel, const | _])
      when vowel in @vowels and const not in @vowels,
      do: <<vowel, const>>

  def vowelconst([_ | rest]), do: vowelconst(rest)
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
Example.vowelconst('trouble')
> "ub"
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to use pattern matching on a `string` to find all the vowel/consonant pairs in a `string`:

```
defmodule A do
  @vowels 'aeiou'  #=> 'aeiou' is shorthand for the list [97, 101, 105, 111, 117]

  def find_vc(<<charcode1::utf8, charcode2::utf8, rest::binary>>)
      when charcode1 in @vowels and charcode2 not in @vowels do

    [<<charcode1::utf8, charcode2::utf8>> | find_vc(rest)]
  end
  def find_vc(<<_::utf8, rest::binary>>) do 
    find_vc(rest)
  end
  def find_vc(<<>>), do: []

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(27)> c("a.ex")                   
warning: redefining module A (current version defined in memory)
  a.ex:1
[A]

iex(28)> A.vowel_consonant("trouble")
["ub"]

iex(29)> A.vowel_consonant("uub")    
["ub"]

iex(31)> A.vowel_consonant("abuk")
["ab", "uk"]

iex(17)> A.vowel_consonant("kabukeieiudi")
["ab", "uk", "ud"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another pattern matching example using [String.next_grapheme/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#next_grapheme/1).  In simple terms, a grapheme is any utf8 character.  `String.next_grapheme()` returns:

1. `{first_char, rest_of_string}` or
2. `nil` when there are no more characters in the string.

--

```
defmodule A do
  @vowels MapSet.new(~w{a e i o u}) 

  def find_vc(str), do: find_vc(String.next_grapheme(str), {{}, []} )

  def find_vc({char, rest}, {{}, acc} ) do
    case char in @vowels do 
      true -> find_vc(String.next_grapheme(rest), {{char}, acc} ) 
      false -> find_vc(String.next_grapheme(rest), {{}, acc} )
    end
  end

  def find_vc({char, rest}, {{vowel}, acc} ) do
    case char in @vowels do
      true -> find_vc(String.next_grapheme(rest), {{char}, acc} )
      false -> find_vc(String.next_grapheme(rest), {{}, [vowel<>char | acc]} )
    end
  end

  def find_vc(nil, {_, acc}), do: Enum.reverse(acc)

end
```

In iex:

```
ex(10)> A.find_vc("eiox")
["ox"]

iex(11)> A.find_vc("eix") 
["ix"]

iex(12)> A.find_vc("eioux")
["ux"]

iex(13)> A.find_vc("adeiouxeed")
["ad", "ux", "ed"]

iex(14)> A.find_vc("dkjloqn")   
["oq"]

iex(15)> A.find_vc("d€xo➞")  
["o➞"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you need such a complicated regex. What's the matter with:

```
~r{[aeiou][^aeiou]}
```

Let's test it out:

```
defmodule A do

  def findall_vc(str) do
    ~r{[aeiou][^aeiou]}
    |>Regex.scan(str)
    |>List.flatten()
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(7)> A.findall_vc "trouble"         
["ub"]

iex(8)> A.findall_vc "dde"
[]

iex(9)> A.findall_vc "ded"
["ed"]

iex(10)> A.findall_vc "aeiddaeixi"
["id", "ix"]

iex(11)> A.findall_vc "dadadad"   
["ad", "ad", "ad"]

iex(12)> A.findall_vc "dakijol"
["ak", "ij", "ol"]
```